# How to configure Jackson to use SNAKE_CASE in Micronaut?

Tags: jackson, micronaut

I have tried to configure jackson to accept JSON using SNAKE_CASE when using Micronaut, however, it doesn't recognize the property `jackson.property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### From Micronaut 1.1.1

*application.yml*

```
jackson:
    property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
```

### Before Micronaut 1.1.1

Micronaut constructs `ObjectMapper` using [`ObjectMapperFactory`](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/io/micronaut/jackson/ObjectMapperFactory.java#L82) that does not set property naming strategy (at least in Micronaut 1.0 GA version, this may change in future releases). The configuration option you have mentioned in the question is not supported by the configuration class, so using it simply does nothing. However, you can replace `ObjectMapperFactory` class with your own custom implementation that constructs `ObjectMapper` in the default way + it sets property naming strategy. Consider following example:

```java
package com.github.wololock.micronaut;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Replaces;
import io.micronaut.jackson.JacksonConfiguration;
import io.micronaut.jackson.ObjectMapperFactory;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Factory
    @Replaces(ObjectMapperFactory.class)
    static class CustomObjectMapperFactory extends ObjectMapperFactory {

        @Override
        @Singleton
        @Replaces(ObjectMapper.class)
        public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Optional<JacksonConfiguration> jacksonConfiguration, Optional<JsonFactory> jsonFactory) {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = super.objectMapper(jacksonConfiguration, jsonFactory);
            mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
            return mapper;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I have added a static class `CustomObjectMapperFactory` to the main `Application` class and I have used `@Replaces` annotation to instruct Micronaut to use this factory class and `objectMapper()` method provided by this custom factory class. The `ObjectMapper` instance we return from this factory is based on the default factory method + it adds:

```java
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

to set expected property naming strategy.

And here is exemplary output I get back in the response after adding this custom factory class:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 7 Nov 2018 19:15:10 GMT
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 38
content-type: application/json

{
    "first_name": "Joe",
    "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

By default (without this custom factory class) the response looked like this:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 7 Nov 2018 19:04:14 GMT
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 36
content-type: application/json

{
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

---

#### UPDATE: Using `BeanCreatedEventListener<ObjectMapper>` instead

There is an alternative way to achieve the same effect that requires even less amount of lines of code. Credits goes to [Micronaut Framework Twitter account](https://twitter.com/micronautfw/status/1060240632885731328) :)

We can use `BeanCreatedEventListener<T>` that reacts to bean creation event and allows us extending the bean that just got created. In this case it means adding a class that implements `BeanCreatedEventListener<ObjectMapper>` and sets property naming strategy:

```java
package com.github.wololock.micronaut;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import io.micronaut.context.event.BeanCreatedEvent;
import io.micronaut.context.event.BeanCreatedEventListener;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Singleton
    static class ObjectMapperBeanEventListener implements BeanCreatedEventListener<ObjectMapper> {

        @Override
        public ObjectMapper onCreated(BeanCreatedEvent<ObjectMapper> event) {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = event.getBean();
            mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
            return mapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Advantages of this solution:

- less lines of code
- one abstraction layer less (we don't have to bother with `ObjectMapperFactory`, we just care about configuring existing `ObjectMapper` bean).

Comment: Nice! I've tried using `BeanInitializedEventListener` to accomplish the same , but the hook has not been picked. Should it work as well?

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be done for this to work with the `BeanCreatedEventListener<ObjectMapper>` approach? So far it doesn't...not sure what am I missing O:)

Comment: Any luck with BeanCreatedEventListener<ObjectMapper> ? In my case it is going inside the onCreated method but no impact on objectmapper. I am trying to set  mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS); and mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For all folks asking here if there is anything wrong with this configuration using the `ObjectMapperBeanEventListener`, I don't think so. I have read the documentation multiple times, trying to implement the same configuration proposed here and that is not working. It's very frustrating. One of the downsides of Micronaut is the poor documentation for its sub-projects (like Micronaut Serialization), the high number of bugs, and the reduced number of contributors for sub-projects.

Answer (score 7):

This is fixed as of Micronaut 1.1.1 in this issue: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1599

Add this to your **application.yml**

```
jackson:
    property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
```

And you can test it with:

```
    @Test
    fun testJackson() {
        val applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run()

        assertThat(applicationContext.getBean(JacksonConfiguration::class.java).propertyNamingStrategy).isEqualTo(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
    }
```