# Adding Jackson KotlinModule to Micronaut JMS

Tags: kotlin, jackson, micronaut

I created a `JMSListener` which listens an AWS SQS queue. I receive message successfully but I cannot deserialize received message to a class without default values.

This is my queue listener function:

```java
@Queue(value = "queuename", concurrency = "1-10", acknowledgeMode = JMSContext.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)
fun receive(@MessageBody sqsMessage: SQSMessageDto) {
    ....
}
```

...and class:

```java
class SQSMessageDto(
    val notificationType: String,
    val mail: Mail,
    val receipt: Receipt
)
```

Function cannot parse deserialize text to SQSMessageDto unless I give default values for fields.

**What I tried?**

It works when I add a breakpoint in debugger mode on `io.micronaut.jms.serdes.DefaultSerializerDeserializer` and register Jackson's KotlinModule manually. (`OBJECT_MAPPER.registerModule(new KotlinModule())`) But I don't know how to make it properly.

Error Message:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of `com.example.sqs.SQSMessageDto` (no Creators,
> like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value
> (no delegate- or property-based Creator)  at [Source:
> (String)"{.......}"]

Answer (score 1):

just use a `BeanCreatedEventListener<ObjectMapper>`
like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195504/7776688

```
@Singleton
static class ObjectMapperBeanEventListener implements BeanCreatedEventListener<ObjectMapper> {

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper onCreated(BeanCreatedEvent<ObjectMapper> event) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = event.getBean();
        mapper.registerModule(new KotlinModule())
        return mapper;
    }
}
```